Partial response due to max tokens reach when using aws bedrock
I am using aws java sdk BedrockRuntimeAsyncClient.invokeModelWithResponseStream which read multiple images as a Multimodal prompt and gives a analyzation output. But i am getting partial response because the response breaks due to max token reached. I am already use max token value for 8192 of claude-3-5-sonnet-20240620 model.  How can i handle such situation which i want to get full response?
Ref:
InvokeModelWithResponseStream
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/java_bedrock-runtime_code_examples.html
